# How to show page header on every page in RDLC report?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

I have to have the page header printed on every page of an RDLC report.

The only options provided are "Print on first page" and "Print on last page".
Is there any way to just show it on every page of a report?

Comment: Do  you want the page header or the column headers in the data table?

Comment: I'd want the page header to be shown on every page.